# Cannot update column value of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update the values of a data frame by using:

```
train.iloc[test_idx][target] = clf.predict(X.iloc[test_idx])
```

clf.predict() returns a numpy array of the length text_idx. This fails to update the value at train.iloc[test_idx][target] and I do not know why. What also confuses me is that if I do something like `train[target] = somenumpyarray` then this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the selectors and select by column first, this should fix the issue.

`train.target.iloc[test_idx] = clf.predict(X.iloc[test_idx])`

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention that test_idx is an array.

Comment: I edited my answer, does this answer your question?